# Notation for a function that maps a point to the solution of an equation

Tags: real-analysis, functions, notation

Consider two functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $g$ be continuously differentiable with respect to $y$.

I would like to define $f$ as follows: $f(x)=y$, where $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is such that
$$
\nabla_y g(x,y) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y) = 0.
$$
That is, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the function $f(x)$ returns a $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ that solves the equation $\nabla_y g(x,y) = 0$.

What could be a short notation for defining this function?

Comment: Such an object isn't even a function in many cases, as a single $x$ can correspond to multiple roots.

Comment: Assume there is a mechanism to choose, among all roots, a unique root.

Comment: This seems similar to continuation. Perhaps some notation from that literature would be helpful? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_continuation#Definitions